# SAS - Row by row Comparison within different ID Variables of Same Dataset and delete ALL Duplicates

Tags: sas, datastep

I need some help in trying to execute a comparison of rows within different ID variable groups, all in a single dataset.

That is, if there is **any** duplicate observation within two or more ID groups, then I'd like to delete the observation entirely.

I want to identify any duplicates between rows of different groups and delete the observation **entirely**.

For example:

```
ID  Value
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 1    D
 1    D
 2    A
 2    C
 3    A
 3    Z
 3    B
```

The output I desire is:

```
ID  Value
 1    D
 3    Z
```

I have looked online extensively, and tried a few things. I thought I could mark the duplicates with a flag and then delete based off that flag.

The flagging code is:

```
data have;
set want;
flag = first.ID ne last.ID;
run;
```

This worked for some cases, but I also got duplicates within the **same** value group flagged.

Therefore the first observation got deleted:

```
ID  Value
 3    Z
```

I also tried:

```
data have;
set want;
flag = first.ID ne last.ID and first.value ne last.value;
run;
```

but that didn't mark any duplicates at all.

I would appreciate any help. 
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks.

Comment: The flags FIRST. and LAST. will have values 1 (true) or 0 (false).  So they are equal when there is only on observation in the group. Or when there are more than 2 observations all but the first and last observations will have matching values for the FIRST and LAST flags since they are neither the first nor the last.

Comment: I do not understand the logic that leads to the observations you want to keep. Why do you want to keep ID=3 and VALUE=Z?  That is not a duplicate.

Comment: I understand deleting 1 D based on your explanation, but why 3 Z?

Comment: @Tom and Python R SAS: I agree. My requirement was that I wanted to keep all non-duplicates. ID=1 and VALUE=Z was a duplicate. Basically I want to delete duplicates that are duplicated across different ID groups, but if they were to be in the same ID group, I'd like to keep the observation. Apologies if the requirements were not clear.

Comment: Your description is still extremely confused. Based on the answer selected it sounds like you want values that are present for only one ID, whether the observation is duplicated or not. Presenting the data sorted by ID instead of by VALUE makes it harder to see what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to do it: sort and deduplicate by value + ID, then keep only rows with values that occur only for a single ID.

```
data have;
input ID  Value $;
cards;
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 1    D
 1    D
 2    A
 2    C
 3    A
 3    Z
 3    B
 ;
run;

proc sort data = have nodupkey;
    by value ID;
run;

data want;
set have;
by value;
if first.value and last.value;
run;
```

proc sql version:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct ID, value from have
group by value
having count(distinct id) =1
order by id
;
quit;
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This is my interpretation of the requirements.
Find levels of value that occur in only 1 ID.

```
data have;
   input ID  Value:$1.;
   cards;
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 1    D
 1    D
 2    A
 2    C
 3    A
 3    Z
 3    B
;;;;
proc print;
proc summary nway; /*Dedup*/
   class id value;
   output out=dedup(drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=occr));
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary nway;
   class value;
   output out=want(drop=_type_)  idgroup(out[1](id)=) sum(occr)=;
   run;
proc print;
   where _freq_ eq 1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: +1000 for translating that question into an actual problem that could be solved.  Wonder if that is really what was wanted?

Comment: This wasn't my requirement - but I found this particularly useful in other situations. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach can use a hash object to track the unique values belonging to a single group.

```
data have; input
ID  Value:& $1.; datalines;
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 1    D
 1    D
 2    A
 2    C
 3    A
 3    Z
 3    B
run;

proc delete data=want;

proc ds2;
  data _null_;
    declare package hash values();
    declare package hash discards();
    declare double idhave;

    method init();
      values.keys([value]);
      values.data([value ID]);
      values.defineDone();

      discards.keys([value]);
      discards.defineDone();
    end;

    method run();
      set have;

      if discards.find() ne 0 then do;
        idhave = id;
        if values.find() eq 0 and id ne idhave then do;
          values.remove();
          discards.add();
        end;
        else
          values.add();
      end;
    end;

    method term();
      values.output('want');
    end;
  enddata;
  run;
quit;

%let syslast = want;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you should do is:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ID value;   
  if not first.value then flag = 1;
  else flag = 0;
run;
```

This basically flags all occurrences of a value except the first for a given ID.

Also I changed want and have assuming you create what you `want` from what you `have`. Also I assume `have` is sorted by ID value order.

Also this will only flag `1 D` above. Not `3 Z`

**Additional Inputs**

Can't you just do a sort to get rid of the duplicates:

```
proc sort data = have out = want nodupkey dupout = not_wanted;
  by ID value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you process the observations by VALUE levels (instead of by ID levels) then you just need keep track of whether any ID is ever different than the first one.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.value);
    set have ;
    by value ;
    if first.value then first_id=id;
    else if id ne first_id then remapped=1;
  end;
  if not remapped;
  keep value id;
run;
```